# How to install an HP C4700 Photosmart printer

Tags: wireless, drivers, printing

I'm trying to install an HP C4700 Photosmart printer. It came with a software CD which I have in my CD drive, but I'm not sure how to use it. As with Windows it just popped up and I believe a wizard took over from there. No, the printer is not connected to my wireless yet and it doesn't have an ethernet cable. This is a brand new printer for me. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Take the disk and make a Christmas tree ornament out of it

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Enter the command

`hp-setup`

Follow the instructions on the screen

Comment: That didnt work Mr. Charles. What came up on the side of my screen was error error

Comment: Error error?  I don't think I've seen that one.

Comment: Make sure hplip is installed on your machine  `sudo apt-get install hplip`

Comment: something isnt right  i just printed a test up page from the printer and it is connected..but when i send something from the computer it isnt working.  I have a HP Pavilion Entertainment PC

Comment: I have an HP dv7-4263cl, and they are not always easy to work with.    Which OS are you running?